# Received number of calls: 0 for textbox onchange function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test the  onchange and onBlur function in jest, no idea why am I getting 0 calls to the function, can anyone please help me out here

RequestThirdParty.tsx

```
`import { useReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client';
import { RdsInput } from 'rds-components-react';
import React from 'react';
import {
  thirdPartyRequestVar,
  onTextChangeHandler,
  checkValidations,
} from '../../StateHandlers/thirdPartyCertificates';
import { requestFormValidation } from '../../../../utils/Validations/Validations';

const RequestedThirdParty = () => {
  const thirdPartyForm = useReactiveVar(thirdPartyRequestVar);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mt-2">
        {thirdPartyForm.map((el, i: number) => (
          <div className="mt-4">
            <RdsInput
              data-testid="business-name"
              error={!!el.businessErrorText}
              label={`Third-party business name ${i !== 0 ? `(${i + 1})` : ''}`}
              maxlength={90}
              name="businessName"
              type="text"
              required
              value={el.businessName}
              onRdsOnBlur={(event) => {
                const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
                if (input.value === '') {
                  onTextChangeHandler(i, 'required', 'businessErrorText');
                } else if (requestFormValidation(input.value) === '') {
                  onTextChangeHandler(i, '', 'businessErrorText');
                }
              }}
              onRdsOnInput={(event) => {
                const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
                checkValidations(i, requestFormValidation(input.value), 'businessErrorText');
                onTextChangeHandler(i, input.value, 'businessName');
              }}
            >
              <span slot="error-text">{el.businessErrorText}</span>
            </RdsInput>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default RequestedThirdParty;
```

spec file test case

```
`  it('should fire textbox change event', async () => {
    const onTextChangeHandler = jest.fn();
    render(<RequestedThirdParty />);
    const inputZip = screen.getByTestId('business-name') as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.change(inputZip, { target: { value: '412307' } });
    expect(inputZip.value).toBe('412307');
    expect(onTextChangeHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });`
```

I am trying to call the jest function on change event of textbox

Comment: Add a sandbox or code snippet so It is easier to make changes

Answer (score 0):

I think the test will not automatically use your `onTextChangeHandler`. You have to setup your mock differently for this to work.

Try something like this:

- import the module:
  `import * as thirdPartyCertificates from '../../StateHandlers/thirdPartyCertificates'; // adjust this depending on your tests path`
- setup the mock:
  `const onTextChangeHandlerMock = jest.spyOn(thirdPartyCertificates, "onTextChangeHandler");`